# CSS Spinning Div Background Color

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have implemented spinning `div`s using CSS animation. Each `div` has an image inside and an on hover the `div` spins. When spinning, the image should be hidden displayed and replaced with text displayed in the `div` with a specific `background-color`.

I want `background-color` to be different for each `div` but as it stands the only way I have found to do it is to have the background color the same for each spinning div. This is defined using `.trigger:hover > .hover-img {` in the CSS.

How can I make the `background-color` different for each spinning `div`?

```css
    .trigger {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    }
    .trigger.large {
    width: 400px;
    }
    .trigger.vertical {
    height: 400px;
    }
    .trigger.vertical * {
    height: 400px;
    }
    .hover-img, .hover-img.hover_effect {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #CCCCB2;
 border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
    width: 400px;
    }
    .trigger:hover > .hover-img {
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #f47878;
    }
    .trigger:hover .hover-img img {
     display: none;
    }
    #container {
    width:960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .row {
    display: flex;
    }
    .col {
    display:inline-block;
    }
    .trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
    width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="col">
            <div class="trigger">
                <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"><img src="STEP1.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="trigger">
                <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"><img src="STEP3.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="trigger">
                <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"><img src="STEP2.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 6</div>
            </div>
            <div class="trigger">
                <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img7"><img src="STEP4.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 7</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Click on <> to replicate the issue with stack snippet.

Comment: They all have unique class's, use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use unique class as told by #Ruddy not a big deal.

```
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img4 {
    background-color: #f00;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img5 {
    background-color: #ff0;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img6 {
    background-color: #000;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img7 {
    background-color: #0ff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the background declaration on `.hover-img`, instead declare it on `.imgX`

```
.img1 { background: white; }
.img2 { background: blue; }
.img3 { background: red; }
.img4 { background: green; }
```